# I'm struggling to add prefixes and suffixes

Tags: python

```
prefixes = 'JKLMNOPQ'
suffix = 'ack'
```

I am meant to add the prefixes and suffixes and Output should be Jack, Kack, Lack, Mack, Nack, Ouack, Pack, Quack. I already got how to add the suffixes to the prefixes but the extra "u" for O and Q throws me off completely.

this is how I did it:

```
for letter in prefixes:
        print(letter + suffix)
```

Comment: it sounds like you need to check `if` the current letter is `Q` or `O` and add a `U` if it is

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you don't make it clear in the question if there are any other conditions but it seems that you simply want to add this extra "u" if the first letter is "o" or "q", you can make a list to store these letters and use an `if` statement to check

```
prefixes = 'JKLMNOPQ'
suffix = 'ack'
add_u_letters = ['O', 'Q']
for letter in prefixes:
    if letter in add_u_letters:
        print(letter + 'u' + suffix)
    else:
        print(letter + suffix)
```

Answer (score 2):

**This should work:**

```py
prefixes = 'JKLMNOPQ'
suffix = 'ack'

for letter in prefixes:
    if letter in 'OQ':
        print(letter + 'u' + suffix)
    else:
        print(letter + suffix)
```

Answer (score 1):

I think a simple if would do that:

```
for letter in prefixes:
    if suffix in ['O','Q']:
       print(letter + 'u' + suffix)
    else:
       print(letter + suffix)
```

Comment: Thank you for responding. This does not work I just tried it in python and it returns:        
Jack
Kack
Lack
Mack
Nack
Oack
Pack
Qack

Comment: Sorry, I didn't check. It should check letter and not suffix in the if.

Answer (score 0):

This is what I wrote

```
prefix = 'JKLMNOPQ' suffix = 'u' suffix2 = 'ack'
 
def ducklings(names):
     for letter in names:
         if letter == 'O' or letter == 'Q':
             print(letter + suffix + suffix2)
         else:
             print(letter + suffix2)
 
ducklings(prefix)
```

Comment: Hi, try to add more details to code. Also code should be in quote block with proper indents, not quoted.

Comment: `preffix` isn't a word in English, and it's one character longer than `suffix`.